# Effect not showing up on guis

Tags: user-interface, lua, roblox

I'm making an effect in my game where it scrolls through some choices and slows down to a stop on one choice.

There's 4 screens and I want each one to play the effect simultaneously, all the guis show up at the same time but the effect never plays. I've marked the part of the code that does the effect in the block of code below:

```
message.chooseduel = function(spins)
    local lobby=workspace.Lobby
    local screens=lobby.Screens
    local n1,n2
    for _, screen in pairs(screens:GetChildren()) do
        local gui=screen.SurfaceGui
        local ds=gui.DuelScreen
        gui.Enabled=true
        for i, v in pairs(ds.Container:GetChildren()) do
            local ll
            local lastpicked       
            local t = ds.Container:GetChildren()
            local menuItems = #t -- number of menu items
            local repeats = 1 -- Repeated
            for R = 65 + spins, 1, -1 do
                ll = t[repeats]
                if ll:IsA("GuiObject") then
                    --**effect**--
                    local newgui = coroutine.wrap(function()
                    print("HI!")
                    ll.BackgroundColor3=Color3.fromRGB(130, 125, 56)
                    wait( R^-.7*.7 ) --
                    ll.BackgroundColor3=ll.BorderColor3
                    repeats = repeats % menuItems + 1
                    end)
                    newgui()
                    --**effect**--
                end
            end
            ll = t[repeats]
            ll.BackgroundColor3=Color3.fromRGB(230, 225, 156)
            n1=string.sub(ll.n1.Image,64)
            n2=string.sub(ll.n2.Image,64)
            print("Returning:",n1,n2)
        end
    end
    wait(2)
    return {n1,n2}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
message.chooseduel = function(spins)
    spins = math.ceil(spins)  -- just making sure.
    local lobby=workspace.Lobby
    local screens=lobby.Screens
    local n1,n2
    for _, screen in pairs(screens:GetChildren()) do
        local gui=screen.SurfaceGui
        local ds=gui.DuelScreen
        gui.Enabled=true
        spawn(function() -- I think this is where the coroutine / async function should start
            local ll
            local lastpicked -- Variable not used
            local t = ds.Container:GetChildren()
            local numMenuItems = #t -- number of menu items
            local current = 1 -- Repeated
            print("HI!")
            for R = 65 + spins, 1, -1 do
                ll = t[current]
                if ll:IsA("GuiObject") then
                    ll.BackgroundColor3=Color3.fromRGB(130, 125, 56)
                    wait( R^-.7*.7 ) --
                    ll.BackgroundColor3=ll.BorderColor3
                    current = current % numMenuItems + 1
                end
            end
            print("BYE!")
            ll = t[current]
            ll.BackgroundColor3=Color3.fromRGB(230, 225, 156)
            n1=string.sub(ll.n1.Image,64) -- um... Interesting. wait what?
            n2=string.sub(ll.n2.Image,64)
            print("Returning:",n1,n2)
        end)
    end
    wait(2)
    return {n1,n2}
end
```

I'm not sure I totally get what you are doing here or how you have things set up, but in general you should try to move coroutines / spawned functions to the outsides of loops.